# Count the numbers that are not divisible by 2, 3, 5

Tags: c#, math

In my program, I think my count variable is not holding the value. What do I do so that it can hold? here`s my code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double a;
        double count = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Numbers : ");
        for (double i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            if (a % 2 != 0 || a % 3 != 0 || a % 5 != 0)
            {
                count = count++;
            }
            //else
            //{

           // }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The Numbers That Are divisible by 2,3,5 are : " + count);
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
```

Comment: "i think my count variable is not holding the value". You are right!

Comment: Do you need divisible or NOT divisible by 2,3,5 numbers?

Comment: If you haven't solved this, please post the current code and a clearer explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 8):

Your mistake is the line `count = count++;`. This does not increase `count` by one. You need to use just `count++;`.

The expression `count++` will increment the value of `count` by one and then return as the expression's value the original value of count. In this case the increment of `count++` happens before the assignment, so `count` is first incremented by one, but then you assign the value of `count++`, that is, the original value, to `count` again, so it does not increase at all.

Comment: i also tried count++ .. but same response here with count = count++

Comment: The behavior is actually undefined (there is no sequence point in that line), but yes, that is the issue. Either use `count++;` or `count = count + 1;`. The former is generally preferred.

Comment: this program also stops onto a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); saying an exception that an input string is not in a correct format..

Comment: @David: count=count++ i; invokes Undefined Behavior in C and in C++ but in C# the behavior is well defined. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Prasoon is right; this is well defined in C#. If this subject interests you, here's an article I wrote about it: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/10/precedence-vs-order-redux.aspx

Comment: Serves me right for not knowing C# well enough. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 7):

Your program lists numbers that are not divisible by *any* of those numbers. If you want to count numbers which aren't divisible by *all* of them then you need to use `if (a % 2 != 0 && a % 3 != 0 && a % 5 != 0)` instead. I would also suggest using integers instead of doubles if possible.

Finally, your print statement says numbers that **are** divisible by 2,3,5, but count is the number of numbers which **are not** divisible by those numbers.

Edit: Are you entering 10 numbers each time you test? I'm not sure what kind of result you will get if you give a blank input.

Comment: i used and operator.. but i continued trying and changed it to or.. btw. the affect of && or || wouldn`t be same here??

Comment: No, using || returns the count of number that are not divisibly by 2 OR not divisibly by 3 OR not divisible by 5. (like: 2, 3 or 5 for example... see his point?)

Using && results in a count of all numbers that are not divisibly by 2 AND not divisibly by 3 AND not divisibly by 5. (like: 7 for example)

Answer (score 2):

Not to add to what jk and David Kanarek said in their answers or what the others the comments on those answers, As pointed out by jk use count+1 instead of count ++ , also a few notes:

1) Your using console.Readline() twice in the loop, so the user will enter 20 inputs but only 10 will be read..

2) Just alittle extra thought on Anton's comment, in your if clause , if you use || your trying to catch any of the conditions being true, in other words:

```
 // a=2

  if (a % 2 != 0 || a % 3 != 0 || a % 5 != 0) // False || True || True = True 
        {
            count = count + 1 ;// count will increase
        }
```

on the other hand, using && :

```
 // a=2

  if (a % 2 != 0 &&  a % 3 != 0 &&  a % 5 != 0) // False && True && True = false
        {
            count = count + 1 ; //count will not increase
        }
```

[A useful Link explaining operators](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpBooleanOperators.aspx)